# Why is previousSibling not working?

Tags: javascript, html

this is demo code so I want only follow the pattern that when user click button it show inner text of anchor in `h3` tag .

My Code

```js
 var a = document.getElementById('btn');
 var b = a.previousSibling.firstChild.innerText;
 alert(b);
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <h3><a href="#"> Heading </a> </h3>
  <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

I am getting this :

```
Error is Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

Comment: make sure your browser doesn't make whitespace into text nodes, which would mean that the linebreak/indent between `</h3><button>` would count as the "previousSibling"

Comment: No, simply use `previousElementSibling` instead.

Comment: @MarcB  i tried that but still same problem

Comment: @Xufox  but that not supported by many browser

Comment: @gaurav The answer linked still answers your question: _“You would probably need to loop through `previousSibling` until you find an `Element` node.”_.

Comment: @gaurav Yes it is. IE 8 isn't a major browser, if you need it you can use a [pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling#Polyfill_for_Internet_Explorer_8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.previousElementSibling) instead

```js
var a = document.getElementById('btn');
var b = a.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerText;
console.log(b);
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <h3><a href="#">Heading</a></h3>
  <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got your sample working in a fiddle here by eliminating whitespace between the button and the closing `</h3>` tag: https://jsfiddle.net/shggo1x4/

```
<div class="box">
   <p> This is a paragraph </p><h3><a href="#"> Heading </a></h3><button id="btn"> Click Me</button>
</div>

var a = document.getElementById('btn') ; 
var b = a.previousSibling.firstChild.innerText;
alert(b) ;
```

previousSibling considers whitespace to be a text node, so as @dippas said, use the **previousElementSibling** property.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: not my downvote, but I wouldn't say that those browsers are being picky - the whitespace _is_ the previous node, and the original error caused by that text node having no child nodes.

Comment: I agree.  That's why I changed my comment less than a minute later.  oh well.  This is what bothers me about SO.  Why not comment, then give me a chance to correct before downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<div class="box">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <h3><a href="#">Heading</a></h3>
  <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>


var a = document.getElementById('btn') ; 
var b = a.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerText ;
alert(b);
```

Comment: This has already been answered — in a better way.